python-mapnik on ubuntu 22.04
I can't use some mapnik comands with python.
I installed python3-mapnik with the command apt install python3-mapnik.
I imported mapnik in python3.10, but when try to use the library, it doesn't work:
import mapnik # ok
mapnik.Projection('+init=epsg:31467') # Any use of projections things
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: Cannot initialize projection '+init=epsg:31467 ' without proj4 support (-DMAPNIK_USE_PROJ4)

I sawin https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/blob/master/src/projection.cpp that -DMAPNIK_USE_PROJ4 seems to not be defined, and I don't know if I can change it.
Do you have any idea of how I can use mapnik on python ?
Thank you

see also https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mapnik/+bug/1987559 and https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/issues/4311

Thank you, this problem only occured on ubuntu 22.04, and python mapnik is working on ubuntu 24.04
